# Errors installing pyspotify

Tags: python, debian, pip

Hi I am having problems installing `pyspotify`. I think i have installed the development headers and `libffi` package but I am still getting errors, here is what happens when I try and install it using pip:

```
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/tmp'
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'pyspotify.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying spotify/api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify
copying spotify/api.processed.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify._spotify.c'
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4
building 'spotify._spotify' extension
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/build
creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify._spotify.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify._spotify.o
build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify._spotify.c:422:28: fatal error: libspotify/api.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libspotify/api.h"
```

> ```
> Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-f_0drg24/pyspotify/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
> 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dn3q3awz-record/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-f_0drg24/pyspotify/
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This shows that it cannot find the development headers:

```
build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/spotify._spotify.c:422:28: fatal error: libspotify/api.h: No such file or directory
```

Have you considered installing the precompiled python-spotify Debian package from http://apt.mopidy.com, or even just installing libspotify-dev from there, to get development headers installed properly?

Comment: Thanks I might try that, I hadn't seen that suggested anywhere else so didn't know to try it, do you know whether the development headers are Python 2 or 3 specific?

Comment: Installation of the python-spotify Debian package is documented at https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/#debian-ubuntu-install-from-apt-mopidy-com

Installation of the development headers is documented at https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/#libspotify

The development headers are C and not related to Python at all.